# Can't import local python module

Tags: python, module

I retrieved the source code of an existing project, even though, while I'm running it it gives me an error while trying to import a module named "geo". The line where the error occurs is:

```
from . import geo
```

The error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name geo
```

I'm running the project using Python 2.7 in a miniConda virtual environnement.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks

Comment: try `import geo` ?

Comment: have you installed the geo package?

Comment: "The line where the error occurs is" Is this part of your code, or part of the other code? If it's part of the other code, did you follow the installation instructions for that code? If it's part of your code, then do you understand how relative imports work? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: It's impossible to tell you what's wrong with the code unless you actually show us how the code is set up - please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - but it's most likely that the cause is some fundamental misunderstanding of how python *packaging* works.

Comment: "The error:" This is not a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough) error message. Copy and paste starting from the line that says `Traceback (most recent call last):` to the end, and format it as code.